# The algebraic structure of repeated root cyclic codes

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

Is there a generator theory for repeated root cyclic codes over finite fields? In other words is the ring $GF(q)[x]/(x^n-1)$ principal when $(n,q)>1$?

Comment: Hi Patrick! Welcome to Math.SE, Good to see you here! You undoubtedly already realized that you can use TeX-code when keying in formulas here. See [this post on our meta site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619) for the details.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki! I have another account by the name of checkpat. Do you know how I could merge the two?

Comment: [On this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) they give instructions on how to merge the accounts. I don't know of an automated way.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. The ideals of $GF(q)[x]/(x^n-1)$ are in bijective correspondence with those ideals of the polynomial ring $GF(q)[x]$ that contain the polynomial $x^n-1$. The latter are all principal ideals, because all ideals of $GF(q)[x]$ are. Furthermore, the lowest degree non-zero polynomial still generates the ideal.

Comment: Thanks JL. But then, why are all classical textbooks and articles assuming (n,q)=1?

Comment: The theory of ideals IS more complicated when $(n,q)>1$. For example, the cyclic codes will no longer be direct sums of simple (or are they called minimal?) cyclic codes. This is because the irreducible factors of $x^n-1$ are no longer simple, so the Chinese Remainder Theorem does not work as well. Consequently (IIRC) not all codes have idempotents attached to them.

Comment: IIRC Karl-Heinz Zimmermann was one of the first coding theorists making major contributions to that theory. He talked about his work in Eurocode '94 in La Bussiere. I'm afraid I am not very familiar with the details.